# how to use sql query as string parameter?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have query which execute with no error or issue

```
select * from table(get_values_in_rows('word1:word2:word3:word4:word5:word6'));
```

but when i use query  as string parameter such as it does not execute

```
select * from table(get_values_in_rows(
'select branch_id from nazim_shift where user_level=5 and lower(nazim_login_id)=:value1'
));
```

Noted:

```
create or replace function get_values_in_rows(pv_colon_values in varchar2) return t_rows_tab is
list_values t_rows_tab := t_rows_tab();
begin

  for i in (SELECT distinct REGEXP_SUBSTR(pv_colon_values, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) colon_values FROM dual
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(pv_colon_values, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
  loop
  list_values.extend;
  list_values(list_values.last) := t_rows(i.colon_values);
  end loop;

  return list_values;

end get_values_in_rows;

select branch_id from nazim_shift where user_level=5 and lower(nazim_login_id)=:value1
```

above query will return colon separated values

we are using oracle 11g

Comment: You use some custom function, we cannot know what it should do

Comment: Nobody knows what your function "get_values_in_rows" might do. You should write it.

Comment: If provided select statement returns a scalar value that is a colon-separated list of something, you need to pass it to your function without quotation marks

Comment: @astentx @Rezu clearly "get_values_in_rows" is a [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function. I would have named it `split()` or `to_table()`, but 'get_values_in_rows' it is. Why the OP is passing the text of a SQL query into it we can only guess.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes, as name may indicate, it should do splitting. But the reason why OP tries to pass a query as an argument is unknown. It may be "overloaded" in the way to receive and execute a query, that's why this was required to clarify blackbox part (especially when there's no any sample data)

Answer (score 0):

That might be the syntax error in your query. `:=` is the assignment operator in PL/SQL and you can not use a `=:` in your query. You should edit your query like this:

```
select branch_id from nazim_shift where user_level=5 and lower(nazim_login_id)=value1;
```

Comment: select * from table(get_values_in_rows(
'select branch_id from nazim_shift where user_level=5 and lower(nazim_login_id)='abc''
)); found missing right parenthesis error

Comment: Check the output of your regex(). That could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the selected branch_id into the function:

```
select column_value as branches
from   nazim_shift ns cross join table(get_values_in_rows(ns.branch_id))
where  user_level = 5
and    lower(nazim_login_id)='def';
```

I would probably write the split function as:

```
create or replace function get_values_in_rows
    ( p_string in varchar2
    , p_delimiter in varchar2 default ':' )
    return t_rows_tab
as
    list_values t_rows_tab := t_rows_tab();
begin
    select distinct regexp_substr(p_string, '[^'||p_delimiter||']+', 1, rownum)
    bulk collect into list_values
    from   dual
    connect by rownum <= regexp_count(trim(p_delimiter from p_string),p_delimiter) +1;

    return list_values;
end get_values_in_rows;
```

But then I would also avoid storing CSV lists in columns. It's better to have a second table where the individual branch IDs are stored as rows, or if you must, use a nested table or varray column.